# traitCollection.userInterfaceIdiom return -1

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, autolayout

I want to check if iPhone or iPad using these codes

```
if traitCollection.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone {
    println("iPhone")
} else {
    println("iPad")
}
```

I tried with iPhone simulators and my iPhone, but it alaways print "iPad"

then I tried to print "traitCollection.userInterfaceIdiom"

```
println(traitCollection.userInterfaceIdiom.rawValue)
```

it print "-1" and not "0" (iPhone) or "1" (iPad)

I don't know where is the problem, I have been searching on google but haven't found what happened here.

Answer (score 6):

You're doing it right. I copied and pasted your code directly into an app, exactly as you have it:

```
if traitCollection.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone {
    println("iPhone")
} else {
    println("iPad")
}
```

In an iPhone simulator, I see `iPhone` in the console. In an iPad simulator, I see `iPad` in the console.

You are probably just running this code at the wrong time. Remember, your trait collection is not set unless your view is *in* the interface. If you want to check at some other time, ask `UIDevice.currentDevice()`, not the trait collection, about the `userInterfaceIdiom`.

Answer (score 0):

The trait collection properties are not known until the view has appeared.

From Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/index.html):

- `UIUserInterfaceIdiomUnspecified`

Used when an object has a trait collection, but it is not in an environment yet. For example, a view that is created, but not put into a view hierarchy.